# My account is Forked.

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I noticed that my account has been forked as:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953889/digerkam
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007222/digerkam

I haven't done anything to do this,
It causes that I couldn't see notifications about different Q&A sites.

How can I merge those?

Comment: Forked!!!!!!!!.

Comment: Forked forks...

Comment: You probably created different account for [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26048/digerkam) either on purpose or by mistake and used that account instead your main account on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think I solve it via help page, but it was very confusing

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd But now my first main account looks 404.. It causes to prevent to see my other accounts, but only second accounts..

Comment: Dunno what happened, what exactly did you do? Can you post the exact steps you took, one by one?

Comment: It looks like the accounts have been merged.

Comment: @ChrisF no, the first account had more reputation and activity on Stack Overflow (as far as I remember from clicking before it was deleted). Only moderator can tell where it's gone to now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Moderator can't see deleted accounts.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you! it took a little while, but now everything looks correct: http://stackexchange.com/users/1027472/digerkam?tab=accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the same OpenID to the two accounts you triggered the automatic merging process. See the [online help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge)

Do this on all your accounts on all sites and the account associations should be restored correctly.